# Python - Dicionário dentro de lista

Tags: python, dicionário

Tenho um dicionario dentro de lista:

Um dicionário pode ser usado para fornecer uma "tabela de dependêcias".
Por exemplo, dependências de disciplinas na faculdade.

Para fazer Cálculo 3, preciso primeiro fazer Cálculo 2 e Vetores.
Para fazer Cálculo 2, preciso primeiro fazer Cálculo 1.
Para fazer Cálculo 1, não há pré-requisito.
Para fazer Vetores, não há pré-requisito.

Isso pode ser representado pelo dicionário a seguir:

dependencias = {
    'calculo3' : ['calculo2', 'vetores']
    'calculo2' : ['calculo1']
}

(As disciplinas sem dependência não precisam ser citadas.)

Note que, ao total, cálculo 3 acaba tendo TRÊS pré-requisitos efetivos:
cálculo 1, cálculo 2 e vetores.

Isso porque cálculo 1 não é citado diretamente mas é requisito indireto.

Preciso criar uma função que mostre essa dependência DIRETA:
Pensei em algo assim:

```
def mostra_dependencias_diretas(dicionario, materia):
    for chave, valor in dicionario.items():
        if chave == materia:
        print(valor)

def test_06_dependencias_diretas(self):
        simples = {
            'calculo3' : ['calculo2', 'vetores'],
            'calculo2' : ['calculo1']
        }

s1 = pega_saida(mostra_dependencias_diretas, simples, 'calculo3')   
self.assertEqual(sorted(s1.split()), ['calculo2', 'vetores'])
mas o meu esta assim:
AssertionError: Lists differ: ["'vetores']", "['calculo2',"] != ['calculo2', 'vetores']
```

Comment: Mas qual é a dúvida? Como fazer uma função para listar as dependências indiretas?

Comment: o método para listar as diretas não está funcionando.

Comment: Fiz o teste [aqui](https://ideone.com/Unv4DX) e exceto pelo erro de indentação do print, parece estar tudo certo. Era para estar printando outro resultado?

Comment: Essa pergunta é essa aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/419580/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-que-recebe-um-dicionario são a mesma.

Comment: se eu fizer o teste:   simples = {
            'calculo3' : ['calculo2', 'vetores'],
            'calculo2' : ['calculo1']
        }   Deveria ser self.assertEqual(sorted(s1.split()), ['calculo2', 'vetores']), mas estou com erro: AssertionError: Lists differ: ["'vetores']", "['calculo2',"] != ['calculo2', 'vetores']